# Convert PyInt to C int crash with release but run through with debug build

Tags: python, c++, api

I have a simple Python API function, parsing variable setting with this Python API and set to a C variable. Python API would expect an int.

```
/**
 * This sets the C var "index".
 */
static void api_set(PyObject* /*self*/, PyObject *arg)
{
   if (!PyInt_Check(arg)) {
      PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError,
            "int argument expected in param.api_set()");
   }

   int32 index = (int32)PyInt_AsLong(arg);
   //std::cout << "set param: " << index << std::endl;  //#for release build, comment out this line then program will crash
   C_interfaceClass.INDEX = index;
}
```

Here is my situation:
Then if I run the debug build, job runs through; but if I run the release build, then job will crash.
Also, for the release build, if I un-comment the "std::cout" line, the job will also run through.

Here is the stack:

```
Thread 1 (Thread 0x7ffff7f8a7c0 (LWP 13723)):
#0  0x00007fffe635286d in waitpid () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007fffe62e4479 in do_system () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#2  0x00007fffe62e47b0 in system () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#3  0x00007fffec284d3f in sst_generate_stack_trace ()
#4  0x00007fffec2656c9 in sst_signal_handler(int) ()
#5  <signal handler called>
#6  PyEval_EvalFrameEx () at Python/ceval.c:1247
#7  0x00007fffe93bb33a in PyEval_EvalCodeEx () at Python/ceval.c:3607
#8  0x00007fffe93bb549 in PyEval_EvalCode () at Python/ceval.c:675
```

Comment: There's a bug somewhere in your code. The bug can be anywhere. Just because the program crashes here doesn't mean that's where the bug is. C++ does not work this way. This is why stackoverflow.com's [help] instructs you to prepare a [mre] that anyone can run ***exactly as shown*** and reproduce your problem. Otherwise, the only thing you can hope for is random guesses as what the problem is. Based on the scant little shown code, there can't be many of them.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Thanks! I am thinking that this can be a general problem. And the two facts are very strange to me.

Comment: Actually, if I comment out this line "C_interfaceClass.INDEX = index;" the job also crashes.